# Possible to template/overwrite STDOUT?

Tags: linux, bash, stdout

I am debugging a call stack and simply outputting `echo` statements from various files.  Flat logs are becoming a little difficult to follow, so I'm curious what the best way to nest output may be.

I thought setting an environment variable to either the number of tabs or as a prefix space/tab string might be the easiest option if I could overload the STDOUT stream. Basically, it would be nice if I could do something like `STDOUT="$TABS$STDOUT"` to keep stacking tab characters at the beginning of the output stream.

But I wasn't sure if it is even possible to overwrite the stream?  For instance, if I wanted to prefix every line with a hyphen+space, is that possible?

Such that:

```
echo foo
echo bar
echo foobar
```

Produces:

```
- foo
- bar
- foobar
```

---

1. Is templating STDOUT possible?
2. What's the suggested method for nesting output, without having to modify all the `echo`/`printf` statements in the many various scripts that might be called?

Comment: You could pipe `yourprog | someprogramthatfixesupstdout` that would then do that or possibly change the `echo` debug lines to include the filename. Standard output has no knowledge of the structure or nesting of your code.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371542/bash-override-echo-to-print-a-custom-prefix-in-a-script?

Comment: I don't get the question. Call stack of what? _echo statements from various files_ - what do you mean by this? _overload the STDOUT stream_ - eh, what?! The easiest for "us" would be if you wrote your question like _How can I get this <example output> from this <example input>_.

Comment: @countermode call stack doesn't matter, the point is I'm echoing from a bunch of files and it could be recursive and output could be from any number of files.  I want to modify the output stream so it indents at each iteration level of recursion.  Also, didn't the example I gave do just that? `echo foo` produces `- foo` without modifying/aliasing `echo`, so STDOUT would be affected, regardless if it was to screen or a file, or it doesn't matter.  I can't explain it any more simply then this.

Comment: Another useful tool, though perhaps not in your case, is [bashdb](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/) the bash debugger. It allows single step, breakpoints, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to do, if you don't mind merging stdout and stderr, is to run with the `-x` flag which makes bash print each command as it is executed with a prefix like `+++` where the number of characters comes from the nesting level. You can then post-process the output, remembering the prefix but suppressing the line, and applying it to any following non-prefixed line, which will be your echo or printf.

For example, take a small factorial script, `myprog`:

```
#!/bin/bash
f(){
        local i=$1
        if [[ "$i" > 1 ]]
        then        echo $((i*$(f $((i-1)))))
        else        echo $i
        fi
        echo "my debug info $i" >&2
}
echo "factorial ${1?} is $(f $1)"
```

Running it with

```
 bash -x myprog 4  |&
 awk '/^+/{ indent=$1; next }
          { print indent " " $0 }'
```

gives you

```
+++++ my debug info 1
++++ my debug info 2
+++ my debug info 3
++ my debug info 4
+ factorial 4 is 24
```

Of course, you can get quite good debug output with line numbers, filenames, and functions by just setting `PS4` with `-x`. Eg

```
PS4='+ ${BASH_SOURCE}:${LINENO}: ${FUNCNAME[0]} - [${SHLVL},${BASH_SUBSHELL}, $?]     '
```

gives you:

```
++ myprog:10: main - [2,1, 0]     f 4
++ myprog:3: f - [2,1, 0]     local i=4
++ myprog:4: f - [2,1, 0]     [[ 4 > 1 ]]
+++ myprog:5: f - [2,2, 0]     f 3
+++ myprog:3: f - [2,2, 0]     local i=3
+++ myprog:4: f - [2,2, 0]     [[ 3 > 1 ]]
++++ myprog:5: f - [2,3, 0]     f 2
++++ myprog:3: f - [2,3, 0]     local i=2
++++ myprog:4: f - [2,3, 0]     [[ 2 > 1 ]]
...
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to debug a series of RC files that are called during the bash startup.  The pipeline is different based on if it's a [non-]interactive and [non-]login shell.  While I want the behavior to be much similar to this, it would be nice to be able to customize/prefix the output buffer for every write so I could populate the last filed called, line number, or whichever I want to populate it as I have a need -- right now it's to prefix with indentations.  I wanted to set this in one primary place without overriding `echo` or other print builtins.